# Rock Paper Scissors program giving me errors.. not sure how to fix

Tags: java

my program keeps giving me the same symbol not found error`your text` and I can't figure out what's wrong! i'm fairly new to using java, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\tMenu\n\n(1) Rock\n(2) Paper\n(3) Scissors" + "\n\nEnter Your Hand (1, 2, or 3): ");
    yourHand = in.nextInt();
    computerHand = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % 3 + 1);
    // rock = 1
    // paper = 2
    // scissors = 3 (this is all for me so i remember)
    if (yourHand == 1 && computerHand == 3) {
        System.out.println("omg yay you win");
    }
    if (yourHand == 2 && computerHand == 1) {
        System.out.println("omg yay you win");
    }
    if (yourHand == 3 && computerHand == 2) {
        System.out.println("omg yay you win");
    }
    
    
    if (yourHand == 3 && computerHand == 1) {
        System.out.println("imagine losing.. embarrassing");
    }
    if (yourHand == 1 && computerHand == 2) {
        System.out.println("imagine losing.. embarrassing");
    }
    if (yourHand == 2 && computerHand == 3) {
        System.out.println("imagine losing.. embarrassing");
    } else {
        system.out.println("tie? idk maybe lol");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `yourHand` and `computerHand` – have you declared those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is different from Python in that you need to declare the type when declaring a variable. Add 'int' in front of 'yourHand' and 'computerHand'.

Your last 'system.out.println' also needs to be capitalized ("System.out.println"). Otherwise it seems to work as intended with these modifications. Wish you the best in learning Java!

Comment: thank you so much!!! program works just as expected now :)